# How to return type what I want?

Tags: android, kotlin

Android Kotlin, `api.openOrder` return type is `BaseResponse<Profile>` ,

what I want code is, If profile.value is not null, the API returns `BaseResponse<Profile>`, otherwise, throw exception:

```
suspend fun openOrder(qty: Int): BaseResponse<Profile> = withContext(IO) {
    profile.value?.apply {
        return@withContext api.openOrder(username, qty, createAuthCode(username))
    } ?: throw Exception()
}
```

but android studio tips this fun return type is `Any`, How to fix it?

Exclude if-else usage, because `profile.value` has a lot of properties, and `profile.value.username`, `profile.value.qty` and many `profile.value.*` is not easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

use `run` instead of `apply`, `run` return lambda result